# Prime divisor rule for an integer N

Tags: primes

Is it true that there can be only one **prime divisor** of **N** which is greater than the **square root** of **N**?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's purely about mathematics.

Comment: by definition of primes..yea..its totally true.

Comment: One or zero prime divisors will be greater than sqrt(n).  For example, no prime divisors of 32 are greater than sqrt(32).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every number is equal to the product of its prime factors.

If two of these prime factors are bigger than the sqrt, then their product alone would be bigger than the number.